# The 18 golden rational tetrahedra

Tags: triangles, recreational-mathematics, solid-geometry, tiling, packing-problem

In 2020, the [59 sporadic rational tetrahedra](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.14232) were identified. More recently, I found [exact solutions for all of them](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/The59SporadicRationalTetrahedra/). Most of them don't pair up well in terms of similar triangles that would allow them to be stuck together.

However, 18 of them are nice and all buildable in the [Zome system](https://vzome.github.io/zome-tetras/). All dihedral angles are rational fractions of $\pi$. Blue and Green struts are multiples of 1/4, Yellow struts are multiples of 1/3 and Red struts are multiples of 1/5.
[image: the 18 golden rational tetrahedra]

Theoretically, they could be rescaled to fit together into some nice shape.  Question: with all of these in some shape, what is the maximum number of completely surrounded edges?

Comment: I would like to you know that when I had read only the first two sentences of this question, I said “This is going to be from Ed Pegg, isn't it?” I admire the way you have such a distinctive oeuvre.